# Quasar object is not defined inside a vuex action function

Tags: quasar-framework

[According to this page](https://quasar.dev/options/the-q-object#outside-of-a-vue-file), I can import `Quasar` object like this outside of a `vue` file:

```
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'

console.log(Quasar.platform.is.ios)
```

I have this vuex action function:

```
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'
import { getServiceProviderSpec, isPageRegistered } from '../../services/ContentProviderService'

export function updateContentProvider(context) {
  console.log(Quasar.platform.is.ios)
  if (Quasar.platform.is.bex) {
    Quasar.bex.send('bex.get.url').then(url => {
      const spec = getServiceProviderSpec(url.data)
      isPageRegistered(spec.domain, spec.page).then(resp => {
        spec.isRegistered = resp.status === 200
        context.commit('setContentProvider', spec)
      })
    }).catch(e => console.log(e))
  } else {
    // just for test
    context.commit('setCurrentUrl', 'https://instagram.com/s4eed')
  }
}
```

What this function does, is not important, but I can't access `Quasar` object here, it's undefined. Actually I have a Button in my vue file, and when clicks I call this action.